# Using Angularjs how I can do ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, angularjs

Here is a drop down menu. I am fetching the drop down values from the database using `AJAX` and `AngularJS`.

**HTML code:**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyController" >
  <select ng-model="myForm.car" ng-options="obj.id as obj.name for obj in myForm.options">
                                </select>
 </div>
</body>
```

**4 js files included:**

```
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="controllers.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-min.js"></script>
<script src="ajaxload.js"></script>
```

**controller.js** contains an angular function. This angular function will make an ajax call and it will call the PHP file. The PHP file will get the result from database. I have done the value fetching from database, but the values are not coming as a response.

**controller.js code:**

```
 angular.module("myApp", [])
            .controller("MyController", function($scope) {
             $scope.myForm = {};
             $scope.myForm.car  = "nissan";
                            
              $.ajax({url: "/getCars/"}).success(function(data) 
              {
                $scope.myForm.options = data;
              })
             });
```

In the PHP file I already fetched the details and stored it in an array. This array I am returning by using `json_encode` method.

```
function getCars()
        {       
          $cars = array
              (
              array("id" => "nissan", "name" => "Nissan"),
              array("id" => "toyota", "name"=> "Toyota"),
              array("id" => "fiat"  , "name"=> "Fiat"),
              array("id" => "Land Rover"  , "name"=> "Land Rover")
              );           
         print json_encode($cars);
         exit;
        }
```

Comment: Why dont u have a look here http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/ajax.html

Comment: have you tried accessing `/getCars/` either from the browser or cURL to see that the problem is indeed in the front-end side?

Comment: yes i tried its working lolski

Comment: Pratik Joshi I tried but its not even entering to the "MyController"  function itself

Comment: don't use jQuery's ajax methods - create an AngularJS `Resource` that represents this object's REST API

Comment: and if you don't want to create a Resource, use AngularJS's built in `$http` method instead of mixing stuff up with jQuery promises.

Comment: Asked 7 years ago !!!